# python variable in command to execute with os.system

Tags: python, linux

Python is driving me crazy; I always have difficulty using variables in PATH. My version is `Python 2.4.3`

```
>>> import os
>>> a = "httpd"
>>> cmd = '/etc/init.d/+a restart'
>>> print cmd
/etc/init.d/+a restart
>>>
```

How do I put a `/etc/init.d/httpd` in `cmd` variable so I can use `os.system(cmd)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python v > 2.7

```
cmd = '/etc/init.d/{} restart'.format(a)
```

or

```
cmd = '/etc/init.d/'+a+' restart'
```

But you should probably look into using `subprocess`.

Comment: Careful, your second version is missing a space

Comment: @mgilson Thanks, fixed.  Also noted that `.format` for newer versions of python, thanks to your answer.

Comment: Actually, the way you have it is only python2.7 and newer.  with python2.6 you'd need `'{0}'` rather than `'{}'`

Comment: epic win... You are my hero :)

Answer (score 2):

you need something like:

```
cmd = '/etc/init.d/%s restart' % a
```

If you need to do multiple substitutions, you could do something like:

```
cmd = '/etc/init.d/%s %s' % ( 'httpd', 'restart' )
```

In this form, `'%s'` is a place holder.  Each `'%s'` gets replaced by an item in the corresponding `tuple` on the right hand side of the `%` operator (which is the string interpolation operator I suppose).  More details can be found in the String Formatting section of the [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Starting with python2.6, there's a new way to format strings using the `.format` method, but I guess that doesn't help you very much.

Comment: Could you explain those %s and % doing there?

Comment: @Satish -- Added some explanation and a link